# Jquery Validation Error Message is showing up in between label and input

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery Validation Plugin to Validate my form. It is working fine but the problem is the validation error message shows up in between label and input. Please check the screenshot below

[image]

But I want to display it on the right side of the input.

Would you please kindly show me how to do it?

Thanks in Advance :)

For my CSS and HTML code for the form please check http://jsfiddle.net/6HmtE/1/

The validation plugin I am using is- 
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Can you include the Javascript on your jsfiddle, please?

Comment: There's no JavaScript/jQuery in that jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks to both Goran Mottram and SenorAmor for you reply. Here's the new link http://jsfiddle.net/6HmtE/5/  .

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the location of your error messages with a `<label for="fieldId" class="error">` - There's a demo of this here showing how you can put the error messages in different arrangements:  http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html

There are also options you can configure:

```
errorContainer: containerName,
errorLabelContainer: $("jQuerySelectorForYourcontainer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` style is incorrect. Try to change it to `right` for the validation messages.

Answer (score 0):

You form should be like this

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="index.html">
<h1>Sign-up form</h1>
<p>This is the basic look of my form without table</p>

<dl> <label for="name">Name </label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required" /> 
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<br />

<label for="company_name">Company Name </label>
<input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" class="required" />
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<br />

<label for = 'email'>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" />
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<br />

<label for ='subject'>Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="required" /> 
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>                       
<br />

<label for ='message'>Message</label>
<textarea cols="8" rows="8" name = 'message'></textarea>
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
<br />


<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :)

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
   },
   //debug:true
});
```